# Помогите с Physics2D.OverlapCircle

Tags: unity3d

Скажите пожалуйста зачем нужен радиус в `Physics2D.OverlapCircle` и почому именно радиус круга а не например площадь квадрата. [Вот](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) API Unity

Comment: Так в описании же всё написано: Check if a collider falls within a **circular area**.

The circle is defined by its centre coordinate in world space and by its radius. - Круг определяется координатами центра и радиусом.

Comment: Как, по-вашему, связан радиус и площадь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Радиус нужен, чтоб определить попадает ли (проходит ли) коллайдер в **КРУГЛУЮ** область. Было бы странным использовать для определения этого свойства что-то другое.

Например, если нужно проверить можно ли кинуть в колодец некий мяч, то логично проверить проходит ли круг в другой, а не квадрат в треугольник.

Для проверки прохождения в прямоугольные области используется [Physics2D.OverlapArea](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapArea.html)